How to simplify this AC electrical circuit
My aim is to find out the currents flowing through R1, L1 and C1.
In the original circuit there is one real current source (I1 and R1). I guess the other current source I5 is ideal, because there is not a resistor near it.
Original circuit:

The question is can I merge the two current sources despite one being real current source in order to simplify the circuit?
Like this:

Would you say what I have done as a simplification is wrong? If it is, what can I do to simplify it correctly?
I tried to change the I1 current source into a voltage one, but I lose information about the current going through the resistor R1 from the original circuit.

No. You cannot combine those two in that way. What analysis tools have you been learning about recently?

I am familiar with the method with Kirchhoff's laws, method with loop currents and method with nodal potentials for analysis of curcuits.

Then can you ground the bottom node and write down the two KCL equations for the left and right side upper nodes? (For the top schematic.)

if you are familiar with nodal then you should be able to form the KCL. (The node voltages work out to some really simple values, by the way.)

HTML entities and <sup> and <sub> markup don't work in the comments, I'm afraid, but MathJAX does. Use format \$ I_L \$, etc.

@ChumChum No no no. That's not KCL. I mean, that may be in the abstract sense that the sum of currents must be zero. But you can say a lot more about each current in terms of the node voltages.

@periblepsis I followed your suggestion. The two KCL equations are:
$I_1$ = $I_R$ + $ I_L $
$I_L$ + $I_5$ = ** $I_C$**
and got that the current going through $I_R$ equals to U1/5 and the current going through the $C_1$ equals to U1/-3j
What about the current going through the inductor $L_1$ ($I_L$)? How can I find it?
$z_{3,4}$

Well, I(R) = (U1 - U0)/5

@ChumChum I needed to read better. Yes you are on the right track. Just call the bottom node zero. Not U0. What is the complete KCL for U1?

2 = $\frac{U1}{5}$ + I(C)

2+j2 = $\frac{U1}{-3j}$ - I(C)

@ChumChum Hmm. You can do better with I(C) and you need to do something with that inductor.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You've put some work into thinking through some of the KCL and I can see better where you need help.
Here's the KCL:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{U_1}{5\:\Omega}+\frac{U_1}{j\,4}&=\frac{U_2}{j\,4}+2\:\text{A}
\\\\
\frac{U_2}{-j\,3}+\frac{U_2}{j\,4}&=\frac{U_1}{j\,4}+\left(2+j\,2\right)\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$
Note that I've included the capacitor and inductor currents. Do you see what I've done above and why?
This can be solved quickly into \$U_1\$ and \$U_2\$. And from those, you can get all the currents.
EDIT: Now that some time has passed (and I think you get the idea from the chat), I'll lay out what a Python/SymPy solver says about the above; for anyone else interested to test themselves:
solve([ 
    Eq( U1/5 + U1/(4*I) , 2 + U2/(4*I) ),
    Eq( U2/(-3*I) + U2/(4*I), U1/(4*I) + (2+2*I) )
      ], [ U1, U2 ])
{U1: 5 - 5*I, U2: 9 - 9*I}

So \$U_1=5\cdot\left(1-j\right)\$ and \$U_2=9\cdot\left(1-j\right)\$. The difference between these two lay across the inductor. So you can take the difference and divide by the inductive impedance to get its current. And so on for the other two parts.
